Why can't you put scanf() on the same line as the variable?
For example:
int number = scanf("%d", &number);


Start by making good use of a nice book. Return values and parameters are a different thing.

The documentation is at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fscanf.html .

Read "The C Programming Language", 2nd edition, by Brian Kernighan and Dennis Ritchie.  Although the language has continued to evolve since the book was written, it's clear, concise, and invaluable.

@MatthewFlaschen: That is not “the documentation.” It is Unix documentation, not C documentation. It should not be linked to for a C question without cautioning the reader that it may contain extensions not defined by the C standard. It is hard for students to navigate all the variations and details of different C implementations, and we should not make it harder for them.

That's a valid point, in this case.  For many functions that are in both the C standard and POSIX, The Open Group notes that POSIX is aligned to the C standard for that particular function.  I see now that this is not one of those aligned functions.  I still think it is an informative source, with the above caveats, but you're welcome to add another link.

Apologies for the tangent @Eric, but K&R is definitely a description of C, with the exception of Chapter 8 (and the prefaces & introduction which describe the motivation).  That said, I agree that it's an incomplete specification, particularly as regards sequence points, and the relevant ISO specifications are the authoritative references.

@TobySpeight: Note that my comment quotes “the documentation.” That indicates it refers to the comment asserting “The documentation is at pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908775/xsh/fscanf.html .” That is the Single UNIX Specification, not the Kernighan and Ritchie book. The Single UNIX Specification is not “the documentation” for C. I did not (yet) speak to the comment about the Kernighan and Ritchie book.

Ah, I see that user wrote two comments, and I only looked back as far as the most recent one.  Sorry for misunderstanding @Eric.

@KarLee what value would expect int result = scanf("%d %d", &number, &value); to hold?

The return value of scanf is the number of items assigned. So, when successful, scanf("%d", &number) returns 1. Then int number = scanf("%d", &number); says to initialize number to 1. That is not what you want.
int number = scanf("%d", &number); also tells scanf to store the result of converting a decimal numeral from input in number. Which happens first, storing the conversion result or storing the return value? Interpreting this gets into a mess with the C standard. It is not worth figuring that out, because you just should not write code like this.

There is a sequence point before executing the assignment. So its clear, that the expression is calculated first. Otherwise a=++a*2 won't work.

@Wiimm It won't work

@4386427 int a =5; a = ++a*2; printf("a=%d\n",a); prints 12 here like expected.

@Wiimm, undefined behaviour is undefined.  That means that anything can happen  - even, sometimes, what you expect.  When that happens, it's at its most dangerous, because you'll have a false sense of security about the results that others will get.

@Wiimm: (a) There is no sequence point in an assignment. a=++a*2 is famously undefined. C++ has recently defined it, but that is a different language. There is a sequence point due to the scanf, which I address below. (b) This is initialization, not assignment…

… (c) If we reason that the assignment by the scanf takes place prior to the storing of the return value in number, this contradicts C 2018 6.7.9 8, which says, emphasis added, “An initializer specifies the initial value stored in an object.” Storing 1 into number cannot be its initial value of number if scanf stores a different value in it previously. This is a contradiction in the C standard, indicating the committee did not anticipate this situation. That is why my answer says this is a mess with the C standard rather than saying the behavior is outright undefined.

@Wiimm Try changing the optimization level of your compiler and see if that still works.  There is no sequence defined by the C standard that specifies when the two different assignments back into a happen in a = ++a*2; actually happen.

@Wiimm: The set of allowed behaviors of undefined behavior is all behaviors. Printing “12” is a behavior, so it is in the set of all behaviors. Therefore, printing “12” is consistent with int a =5; a = ++a*2; printf("a=%d\n",a); having undefined behavior.

My mistake was that I thought the assignment was a sequence point. I looked it up and now I know better. Fortunately, I never used expressions like a=++a*2. I would always write it a=(a+1)*2.
